# Parse Solr output in python

Tags: python, parsing, solr, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a solr output of the form:

```
<doc>
<str name="source">source:A</str>
<str name="url">URL:A</str>
<date name="p_date">2012-09-08T10:02:01Z</date>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="source">source:B</str>
<str name="url">URL:B</str>
<date name="p_date">2012-08-08T11:02:01Z</date>
</doc>
```

I am keen on using beautiful soup (versions that have BeautifulStoneSoup; I think prior to BS4) for parsing the docs.
I have used beautiful soup for HTML parsing but some how I am not able to find a effecient way to extract the contents of the  tag.

I have written:

```
for tags in soup('doc'):
    print tags.renderContents()
```

I do sense that I can work my way through it forcibly to get the outputs (like say 'soup'ing it again), but would appreciate an effecient solution to extract data.
My output required is:

```
source:A
URL:A
2012-09-08T10:02:01Z
source:B
URL:B
2012-08-08T11:02:01Z
```

Thanks

Comment: renderContents() just converts each subtree to HTML. Why don't you iterator over all src nodes and output their text attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a XML parser for task instead; [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is included with Python:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# `ET.fromstring()` expects a string containing XML to parse.
# tree = ET.fromstring(solrdata)  
# Use `ET.parse()` for a filename or open file object, such as returned by urllib2:
ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for doc in tree.findall('.//doc'):
    for elem in doc:
        print elem.attrib['name'], elem.text
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, considering its included in Python. I tried the code (only change being solr data replaced with the xml retrieved) and I get the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(f.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 579, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")

Comment: The actual error is missing there.. `parse()` expects a filename or open file object. Use `fromstring()` if you have the data in a string.

Comment: Oh sorry. The error is IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: I am not sure why this should come. I am using urllib2 to query solr and I get the entire xml in browser view. Even print f.read() prints the xml out, any idea why this error should come??

Comment: @AjayNair: When using `urllib2`, do *not* call `read()` on the result, just pass the response (which is a file-like object) to `parse`:  `resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)` then `tree = ET.parse(resp)`.

Comment: Tried exactly as suggested, compiles fine but fails to print anything:                                                        print tree.getroot().tag
for doc in tree.findall('doc'):
        print "HERE"
        for elem in doc:
                    print elem.attrib['name'], elem.text
This does not print Here, but it prints the root tag fine

Comment: @AjayNair: That always trips me up; updated to use XPath to make ET see sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use this particular output format? Solr supports Python output format out of the box (in version 4 at least), just use wt=python in the query.

Comment: Wow did not know that ! My parsers have already revolved around Beautiful soup but I am using this for the future !! Thanks